# rspec - matcher for one of choices

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have method returning random value from the predefined array (namely: `[ 'value1', 'value2']`).
How should I test that with rspec?

I'd like to do something like:

```
expect(FooClass.new.value).to be_in ['value1', 'value2']
```

Any way to do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use this

```
expect(['value1', 'value2']).to include(FooClass.new.value)
```

Or a simple Boolean match

```
expect(['value1', 'value2'].include? FooClass.new.value).to be true
```

Comment: Prefer the first version (i.e. `.to include(...)`). It will show you the value that is not in the list when the test fails. The second version will only report that `false` is not `true`, which isn't very helpful.

Comment: A slightly nicer syntax if using Rails IMO: `expect(FooClass.new.value.in?(['value1', 'value2'])).to be true`

Answer (score 9):

Also, there is an `or`

```
expect('value').to eq('value1').or eq('value2')
```

Advantages:

1. It sounds like normal English.
2. The error message is a bit longer but contains all relevant info:

```
expected: "value1"
    got: "value"

...or:

expected: "value2"
    got: "value"
```

4. As [muirbot](https://stackoverflow.com/users/352526/muirbot) pointed out you should pass the value you are testing to `expect()`, not the other way.
5. It's more flexible, it will work if someone came here looking for a solution to something like:

```
expect({one: 1, two: 2, three: 3}).to have_key(:one).or have_key(:first)
```

Answer (score 4):

This does work, but is unconventional because the value you pass to `expect` should be the value you're testing.

```
expect(['value1', 'value2']).to include(FooClass.new.value)
```

I think it would be better to do

```
expect(Foo.new.value).to satisfy { |value| ['value1', 'value2'].include?(value) }
```

This will also give you a more accurate message when your test fails.

Comment: I disagree. Let's say `Foo.new.value` evaluates to `"value"`; the first statement would result in the error `expected ["value1", "value2"] to include "value"`, but the second statement would result in the error `expected "value" to satisfy block`. IMO the satisfy block is unnecessary and results in a significantly less transparent/readable error message.

Answer (score 4):

If you need this behavior often, you can write your own matcher.  Here is the one I wrote - you can stick this in your spec file directly or into any file included by your test suite:

```
RSpec::Matchers.define(:be_one_of) do |expected|
  match do |actual|
    expected.include?(actual)
  end

  failure_message do |actual|
    "expected one of #{expected}, got #{actual}"
  end
end
```

This has a nicer failure message than any of the other answers so far (in my opinion).  For instance:

```
Failures:

  1) mydata is either empty or a list
     Failure/Error: expect(mydata.class).to(be_one_of([NilClass, Array]))
       expected one of [NilClass, Array], got String
```

Or you can customize the error message if some other wording makes more sense to you.